# JTable hidden under JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a problem with `JScrollPane` - it looks like it lays over my `JTable`.

I have made a `JTable` without `JScrollPane` and everything seems to be fine - everything gets loaded as I wish and so on - but when I try to add `JScrollPane` everything goes wrong - only the column names are showing.

This is my code...

```
projectTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
ProjectTableModel ptm = new ProjectTableModel();
projectTable.setModel(ptm);

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(projectTable);
```

Is it a problem with positioning components? Could someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: Please give an example how you add your JTable und JScrollPane to the parent container.

Comment: You can provide a screenshot for better result. Here is a [guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). Please keep the image size small

Comment: I can't post the image - got not enough reputation( I'm new here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle `JTable` tutorial contains a section about ['Adding a table to a container'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show), where the container in the example is a `JScrollPane`